# How to Perform Timing Subtraction using Moment Js?

Tags: momentjs

Iam trying to perform Subtraction in **Momentjs**:-

```
// Find the duration between two dates
                var breakfast1 = moment('11:32','HH:mm');
                var lunch1 = moment('12:52','HH:mm');
                alert( moment.duration(lunch1 - breakfast1).humanize() + ' between meals' ); // 1 hours between meals
```

**Output is alerting Only Hours .But How can I get "01:20"as Output Instead of 1 hour  Any Ideas ?**

how to generate Minutes along with Hours

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.humanize() will always round to a specific interval.  Break your code up and manually create the display you want...

```
            var breakfast1 = moment('11:32','HH:mm');
            var lunch1 = moment('12:52','HH:mm');
            var dur = moment.duration(lunch1 - breakfast1);
            alert( dur.hours() + ":" + dur.minutes() + ' between meals' );
```