# How do I calculate time difference in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I get time in string format and I want to find time difference between then in minutes. How would I do this ?

Comment: What is the outcome you expect? that doesn't even make sense.

Comment: Why can't you just write a JS function in your controller and call that instead?

Comment: `date` filter expects a `date_expression` (Date to format either as Date object, milliseconds (string or number) or various ISO 8601 datetime string formats) in input. "hh:mm" is not a `date_expression`... (See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date).

Comment: this may hepl your cause http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29995259/momentjs-timing-subtraction

Comment: I am expecting, it should print 40 mins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [Moment](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment) library:

```
moment.utc(moment(time_stop.diff(moment(time_start))).format("HH:mm")
```

You can wrap this call in a function:

```
$scope.timeDifference = function(start, end) {
  return moment.utc(moment(end).diff(moment(start))).format("HH:mm");
}
```

And then, in your view:

```
{{ timeDifference("15:40", "16:20") }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to get the difference in hours, minutes and seconds:

```
var date1 = new Date("October 13, 2014 16:00:00");
var date2 = new Date("October 13, 2014 16:10:00");
var diffMs = Math.abs(date1 - date2); // milliseconds between date1 & date2
var diffDays = Math.round(diffMs / 86400000); // days
var diffHrs = Math.round((diffMs % 86400000) / 3600000); // hours
var diffMins = Math.round(((diffMs % 86400000) % 3600000) / 60000); // minutes
console.log(diffDays + " days, " + diffHrs + " hours, " + diffMins + " minutes");
```

Using this code you should be able to make your filter.